# Addressing a "numbered" variable when moving slider, Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

In my Mac OS X project I have a slider and a couple of "numbered" NSImageView outlets.  Depending on the sliders value I would like to address the corresponding NSImageView for further actions.

**Something like this:**

```
sliderRed value == 1 -> red1  
sliderRed value == 2 -> red2  
sliderRed value == 3 -> red3  
sliderRed value == 4 -> red4
... and so forth
```

At the Moment I don´t see how to do this and I don´t want to use case constructs.

Any ideas how to do this?

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSSlider *sliderRed;

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSImageView *red1;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSImageView *red2;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSImageView *red3;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSImageView *red4;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSImageView *red5;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSImageView *red6;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSImageView *red7;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSImageView *red8;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSImageView *red9;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSImageView *red10;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSImageView *red11;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSImageView *red12;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSImageView *red13;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSImageView *red14;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSImageView *red15;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Key-Value Coding:

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"red%d", sliderValue];
NSImageView *imageView = [self valueForKey:key];
```

The disadvantage is that the compiler cannot check the validity of the key. If `sliderValue`
is outside the range 1 .. 15 (in your case) you will get a runtime exception.

Comment: Validity is not a problem here. It will never be out of range.  Thanks a lot for this great hint..

Comment: Well, tag checking is faster that key(string) checking. This solution is nice, but one of my question arise here is that how will you iterate through all the nsImageViews ? Will you not require an array or a set holding all these nsImageViews ?

Comment: This project is pretty simple. The red NSImageViews are made hidden or not. That depends on the slider. The only thing I need is a pointer to the current red. This solution is perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tags to all your NSImageView(s)

```
red1.tag = 1;
red2.tag = 2;
.
.
.
red15.tag = 15;
```

Now keep these NSImageView instances in an array;

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfImageViews = [NSMutableArray array];
[arrayOfImageViews addObject:red1];
[arrayOfImageViews addObject:red2];
.
.
.
[arrayOfImageViews addObject:red15];
```

Once, this is done, you can loop through the elements of array on a specific slider value.

```
NSImageView *selectedImageView = nil;
//Lets say your slider value is 7 for now.
for(NSImageView *imageView in arrayOfImageViews)
{
 if(imageView.tag==mySlider.value)
 {
  selectedImageView = imageView;
  break;
 }
}
```

After this loop ends, you will have you NSImageView in the selectedImageView. You can use it to do your tasks now.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I came up with so far. But I think of something like this. First create the correct variable as string: NSString *pointerText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"_red%i",[_sliderRed intValue]]; In case [_sliderRed intValue] equals 1 pointerText will be "_red1". In 4D it is possible to create a pointer to a variable with that name. I hope it´s understandable.

Comment: Nope, I don't get what is 4D here. Can you explain ?

Comment: Plus, I think that even though you apply a formatted key, you'll still require some array or a set to hold the nsimageviews all together to iterate.